# wrap 6 li elements together on a long list

Tags: jquery

I have a long list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
    <li>item 11</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

and I want to somehow wrap some divs around them like this:

```
<ul>
    <div>
        <li>item 1</li>
        ...
        <li>item 6</li>
    </div>

    <div>
        <li>item 7</li>
        ...
        <li>item 12</li>
    </div>

    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</ul>
```

How can I accomplish this?

I tryed `.after('</div><div>')`; but it's not working, it adds a `<div></div>`.

Comment: `ul` doesn't accept any other children than `li` - so don't try such a thing! Work with classes `<li class="group1">` instead.

Comment: i know it is not valid, but since it will added in the DOM i don't have to worry about html validation

Comment: Just because it would be difficult to validate the page using conventional validators does not suddenly mean you don't have to worry about it not being valid. Browsers parse HTML based on rules - break those rules and you have no control over how (if at all) your content will be rendered. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this to quickly wrap them resulting in proper HTML like this:

```
var lis = $("ul li");
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i+=6) {
  lis.slice(i, i+6).wrapAll("<li class='li_group'><ul></ul></li>");
}
```

This results in:

```
<ul>
  <li class='li_group'>
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
      <li>item 4</li>
      <li>item 5</li>
      <li>item 6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='li_group'>
    <ul>
      <li>item 7</li>
      <li>item 8</li>
      <li>item 9</li>
      <li>item 10</li>
      <li>item 11</li>
      <li>item 12</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...      
</ul>
```

Just style `li_group` however you want visually.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (well, you can, but you should not) insert `DIV` elements in a list, since `UL` can only contain `LI` elements.

What you can do, is create a nested list `UL-> LI -> UL -> LI, LI, LI`. Another solution is to assign some specific CSS class to the items that have to be bound together and then apply some specific style to those elements.

UPDATE: if you really need to do that, you can try this:

```
var d= $("ul").prepend("<DIV />");
var itms = $("ul li:lt(6)");
d.append(items);
```

Comment: Well I think the question is not that: I insert ul or div, is that how to wrap every 6 li-s in a tag ...

Comment: use the `:lt(x)` selector to find first x elements in your set. Then `append()` to the nesting element (see my updated post)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery wrap :

```
$('li').each(function() {
     $(this).wrap($('<div/>', { 'class': 'myClass'}));
   });
```

This should wrap every `li` with `<div class="myClass">` at the beginning and `</div>` at the end of every div.

Answer (score 0):

I just built my own version of your problem with jQuery. Figured I would share it since I couldn't find the answer myself, hope it helps.

This is built thinking that you have a ul-li list that is already created and you cannot group it together when it is being created.

```
var $liBlockCount = parseInt($('ul li').length/10);
var $lis = $('ul li');

if($liBlockCount > 1)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < $liBlockCount; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            $lis.filter(':lt(10)').wrapAll('<span class="section'+i+'"></span>');
        } else {
            $lis.filter(':gt('+((i*10)-1)+'):lt(10)').wrapAll('<span class="section'+i+'"></span>');
            // chaining gt and lt is tricky, since gt starts from 0 and lt starts from gt. So I am using lt(10) to get the next 10.
        }
    }
} else {
    console.log('less than 11 items in list');
}
```